# Regex Java Scanner Delimiter

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read this pattern... What is the `Scanner.useDelimiter` for this?

This input is:

> 489 490-1; 491-1; 492-1; 493-1; 494-1; 495-1; 496-1; 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   490 491-1; 492-1; 493-1; 494-1; 495-1; 496-1; 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   491 492-1; 493-1; 494-1; 495-1; 496-1; 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   492 493-1; 494-1; 495-1; 496-1; 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   493 494-1; 495-1; 496-1; 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   494 495-1; 496-1; 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   495 496-1; 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   496 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   497 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;

what I need of output is like:

> 489
>
> 490
>
> 1
>
> 491
>
> 1
>
> 492
>
> 1
>
> 493
>
> 1

I tried this delimiter but it didn't work:
`Scanner(readerFile).useDelimiter("\\s*-\\s*|;\\s*|\\s*");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea seems to be to split on anything that is non-numeric, so give this one a try:

```
Scanner(readerFile).useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");
```

Comment: one question, if I don't want to go for the next line, for example, 

3, 4, 5 \n
2, 3, 2 \n
and I want to put 3 in one variable and 4, 5 in one collection, and after that 2 in the variable and 3, 2 in one collection. If my delimiter go to the next line he put all in the same variable.

Comment: srry, i press enter before complete ^^

Comment: I think it's better if you ask a new question about this. Even if I understood what you need exactly, it would be hard to fit the answer in a comment.